# Result of inject is nil

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to accumulate some values if they match a condition.
Why is this snippet returning nil, when I would expect it to return 2?

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 8], [4, 2]].inject(0) { |s, e| s + e[1] if e[0] <= 1}
```

Isn't `inject` the right method for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return s;

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 8], [4, 2]].inject(0) { |s, e| s += e[1] if e[0] <= 1; s}
```

Little cleaner

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 8], [4, 2]].inject(0){|s,(k,v)| s += (k<2 ? v : 0)}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just found out but did it differently: x = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 8], [4, 2]].inject(0) { |s, e| (s + e[1] if e[0] <= 1) || s}
is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 8], [4, 2]].inject(0){|s,(k,v)| s += (k<2 ? v : 0)}`

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in multiple steps:

```
>> a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 8], [4, 2]]
>> a.select { |e| e.first <= 1 }.inject(0) { |s, e| s += e.last }
=> 2
>> a.select { |e| e.first <= 1 }.map(&:last).inject(0, :+)
=> 2
```

Doing it all with a single `inject` should be more efficient but breaking it into pieces might be cleaner and the speed difference won't be noticeable unless you have really large arrays.

If you don't mind emulating a pointer with a Hash or Array, you can do it with `each_with_object`:

```
>> a.each_with_object({ :sum => 0 }) { |(k,v), m| m[:sum] += v if k <= 1 }[:sum]
=> 2
>> a.each_with_object([0]) { |(k,v), m| m[0] += v if k <= 1 }.first
=> 2
```

The result of your `inject` block is used as the value of `s` on the next call to your block. On the second iterator, this:

```
s + e[1] if e[0] <= 1
```

will have a value of `nil` because `e[0]` will be 2. Subsequent iterations also return `nil` from your block because every `e[0]` is larger than 1 except the first one. This is why you need to return `s` from your block. If you had an array like this:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 8], [4, 2], [1, 11]]
```

then you wouldn't even get `nil` out of your `inject`, you'd just can an exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

when your block tried to add 11 to `nil`.

Comment: Wow, 2 more ways of doing the same - seemingly trivial - operation. Thanks :o)

Comment: @Pierre: I could probably come up with several more if I was feeling playful but I think I'll sleep instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
xs.map { |k, v| v if k <= 1 }.compact.inject(0, :+)
```

Note how Ruby suffers a bit from the lack of list-comprehensions and we have to (somewhat inefficiently) emulate it with `map + compact`. In a language with LC it'd look better: `sum(v for (k, v) in xs if k <= 1)`.

Comment: There's also `each_with_object` and an emulating pointer (`a.each_with_object({ :sum => 0 }) { |(k,v), m| m[:sum] += v if k <= 1 }[:sum]`) but now we're starting to get silly :)

Comment: @mu: I am kind of a functional zealot, so I'd only use `each_with_object` at gunpoint ;-)

Comment: I'm a "use whatever you got" zealot and a professional heretic to boot :)